# How can I capture the source URL of a downloading PDF file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am trying to capture the download source url of a PDF file. The URL changes dynamically.

How can I capture the URL via Javascript.

Comment: How do you start the download? Usually to download the document you should follow a link, that link should have the url

Comment: The url keep changing. It is dynamically generated by a different domain. It's cross domain

Comment: But do your users access it physically following a link or it's somehow injected into their browsers? In any way, when the download starts your client code should know where the document is located, otherwise the browser wouldn't be capable to download it.